# Send multiples emails using multiples username and password with php mailer?

Tags: php

Well i got this code, it works but i need to set every loop the PHPMailer, idk if it's good but if i don't set it every loop the from don't change always come the first that i set, look:

```
foreach($this->users as $v)
{   
    $this->phpmailer = new PHPMailer();

    $this->phpmailer->IsSMTP();
    $this->phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $this->phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    $this->phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $this->phpmailer->Port = 465;

    $this->phpmailer->ClearAllRecipients();
    $this->phpmailer->AddAddress($v['email']);

    $this->phpmailer->Username = $v['email_user'];
    $this->phpmailer->Password = $v['email_pass'];

    $this->phpmailer->From = $v['email_user'];
    $this->phpmailer->FromName = $v['email_name'];
```

...

it works but i'm setting PHPMailer every loop but if i do:

```
$this->phpmailer = new PHPMailer();

$this->phpmailer->IsSMTP();
$this->phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$this->phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$this->phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$this->phpmailer->Port = 465;

foreach($this->users as $v)
{       
    $this->phpmailer->ClearAllRecipients();
    $this->phpmailer->AddAddress($v['email']);

    $this->phpmailer->Username = $v['email_user'];
    $this->phpmailer->Password = $v['email_pass'];

    $this->phpmailer->From = $v['email_user'];
    $this->phpmailer->FromName = $v['email_name'];

...
```

it will work but the from doesn't change every loop.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a solution for you but wanted to share my experience with PHPMailer: I've had to create an entirely new object for each mail I send to get the results I want, even when the email is identical but has a different recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. Is error reporting set to show all errors? Is anything failing from phpMailer? And this is unlikely, but I just saw a similar issue where running object loops polluted a log and preventing the script from executing correctly.

I hope this helps. Please let me know what you find.